# Throttle/limit android.app.DownloadManager via code?

Tags: android, 3g, download-manager

In my code I'm using the android.app.DownloadManager to download some assets required by our app. Sometimes it's 2 things, other times it might be 20 things. The problem is, that even on 3G if I call 'enque(Download.Request)' with my request, it starts downloading all 20 things at once. I expected it to queue them up, and maybe download 3 or so at a time, not start downloading all 20 (it actually does, they all start progressing).

Is there anyway to just get it to download say 2 or 3 at a time, so that those downloads go faster, and then starts the others?

Comment: Hey, have you solved it? I have similar problem. It starts download 2 files at the same time